# submit the value of check box in database

Tags: php

```
<?php 
    $dates = $day1 ;
    echo "<p>";
    for($i=0;$i<count($dates);$i++) {
        if($i>0 && ($i%3==0)) { echo "</p><p>"; }
        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='dates[".$dates."]' /><label>".$dates[$i]."</label>";
    }
    echo "</p>";
?>
```

whan i use this output will be desire Ex

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

but i want send his data in the databse but
only a array will be send into the database `$_post[dates`
so can any on tell me how can i send the data in the database

Comment: Frame the question with appropriate subject please did not get what you mean by this submit the of check box in database

Comment: What is $day1/$dates? you treat it as an array with count, then echo it in the name of the checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
    $dates = $day1 ;
    echo "<p>";
    for($i=0;$i<count($dates);$i++) {
        if(empty($dates[$i]))           ///
             continue;                  // 

        if($i>0 && ($i%3==0)) { echo "</p><p>"; }
        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='dates[]' value='".$dates[$i]."'/><label>".$dates[$i]."</label>";
    }
    echo "</p>";
?>
```

at the time of saving in to data base use

```
$dates = implode(',', $_POST['dates']);  // will save date in format of 1,2,3,4
```

at the time retrieving it again from database use

```
$dates = explode(',', $dateFromDB);   // this will give you array of dates
```

Comment: $dates = implode(',', $_POST['dates']); whan i use this one Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting ',' or ';' . when i echo this one itwill show me nothing . can you little describe it

Comment: echo $_POST['dates'];  check what is the value of it.

Comment: and did you change the line  echo "<input type='checkbox' name='dates[]' value='".$dates[$i]."'/><label>".$dates[$i]."</label>";

Comment: tahnks a lot garuav just tell me on more thing when . when i use the value of $day1 it will show me one blank entery what can i do for remove the blank entry example it will show a checkbox without an entry. what can i do

Comment: check in loop for if(empty($dates[$i])) continue;

Comment: garuv can you liitle explain with code that where should i put the if(empty($dates[$i])) continue on my code. bcoz i not able to delete the last entry thanks

Comment: you can accept this as an answer, by clicking on right mark. just left side of this question.